# Committing in git now requires gpg?

Tags: git, shell, github, terminal

Just a couple days ago I was able to use git perfectly fine.

Today, I tried to git commit on my own public repo and got this message:

```
git error: cannot run /usr/local/bin/gpg:
No such file or directory error: could not run gpg. 
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

I ended up installing gtg and ran through [Github's instructions](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-gpg-key/) on getting gtg configured and such.

Now, the commit command works but I have to enter my gtg password for every commit I do.

I understand this is more secure and probably a better way to use git, but what happened to when I was able to simply commit without any gtg errors? I liked only having to deal with authentication when I would push, entering my Github.com credentials.

Is there a way to disable gtg so I don't get the `git error: cannot run /usr/local/bin/gpg` error when I commit?

Some additional details:

- I'm not completely certain what I did to my computer that caused git to throw the initial gtg errors that weren't present before. I was learning to use Jekyll a couple days ago and that required me to install homebrew. Not sure if that had anything to do with it.
- I'm running Mac OS X El Capitan

Comment: What is the output of `git config --global --list | grep commit` I suspect you have `commit.gpgsign=true`

Comment: Wow, you're right! I just ran `vim ~/.gitconfig`, found the `gpgsign` line, and changed it to false. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @andlrc: You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

What is the output of the command below. I suspect you have `commit.gpgsign=true`

```
git config --global --list | grep commit
```

You can disable it with

```
git config --global --add commit.gpgsign false
```

or by removing the line manually from `~/.gitconfig`.

Comment: Nice! That's actually a more seamless fix than what I did by editing the actual config file. Thanks again! I found zero useful information when Googling my error so I really hope this question will rank in Google for relevant terms to help others out.

Comment: Is that necessarily a bad thing?

Comment: Question: should the command to disable it be: `git config --global --add commit.gpgsign false` (notice the `commit.gpgsign` instead of `config.gpgsign` like you currently have it)?  I assume that was a typo?

Answer (score 0):

Special thanks to [andlrc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/887539/andlrc) for helping me out with this one!

Here's how to fix this problem:

**Step 1**:

In your Terminal, enter the command `vim ~/.gitconfig`. If you prefer a different text editor than vim, of course you can open ~/.gitconfig with that instead.

**Step 2**

Look for the line of code that says `gpgsign = true`. Change it to `gpgsign = false`.

**Step 3**

Save the file and try to `git commit` again. It should work!

Comment: You can also use `git config --global --edit` (I admit I just run `vi ~/.gitconfig` with vi aliased to vim, myself).  This runs your `core.editor` on the config file, wherever it may be.  If you have one of those systems with the obnoxious XDG_HOME stuff in it, your git config file may be there instead of in `$HOME`.